# How can I change property values in a file using Ant?

Tags: ant, properties

Example input:

```
SERVER_NAME=server1
PROFILE_NAME=profile1
...
```

Example output:

```
SERVER_NAME=server3
PROFILE_NAME=profile3
...
```

This file will use in `applicationContext.xml`. I've tried

```
<copy file="${web.dir}/jexamples.css_tpl"
         tofile="${web.dir}/jexamples.css" >
    <filterchain>
       <replacetokens>
            <token key="SERVER_NAME" value="server2"/>
            <token key="PROFILE_NAME" value="profi"/>

        </replacetokens>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `filterchain` is ok, but your source file should look like this:

```
SERVER_NAME=@SERVER_NAME@
PROFILE_NAME=@PROFILE_NAME@
```

This code (as provided by you)

```
<copy file="${web.dir}/jexamples.css_tpl"
         tofile="${web.dir}/jexamples.css" >
    <filterchain>
       <replacetokens>
            <token key="SERVER_NAME" value="server2"/>
            <token key="PROFILE_NAME" value="profi"/>
        </replacetokens>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

replaces the tokens and gives you

```
SERVER_NAME=server2
PROFILE_NAME=profi
```

---

If you want to keep your original file as you have it now, one way would be to use [`replaceregex`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex):

```
<filterchain>
  <tokenfilter>
    <replaceregex pattern="^[ \t]*SERVER_NAME[ \t]*=.*$"
                  replace="SERVER_NAME=server2"/>
    <replaceregex pattern="^[ \t]*PROFILE_NAME[ \t]*=.*$"
                  replace="PROFILE_NAME=profi"/>
  </tokenfilter>
</filterchain>
```

This would replace every line starting with `SERVER_NAME=` by `SERVER_NAME=server2` (same for `PROFILE_NAME=`). This will return get you the output you described.

`[ \t]*` is to ignore whitespace.

Comment: is it possible to change property value without tokens@@ ?

Comment: How can i pass a or more arguments to ant,I do not want to use source files to set the var and value such you show `SERVER_NAME=server2` I hope pass the args when i run the ant build file in eclipse.

Comment: @janwen: This is a different question, so we should not mess up this one. Please ask a new question (a link to this question might be useful).

Answer (score 8):

Cleaner solution is using "propertyfile" ant task - see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html

```
<copy file="${web.dir}/jexamples.css_tpl"
     tofile="${web.dir}/jexamples.css" />
<propertyfile file="${web.dir}/jexamples.css">
    <entry key="SERVER_NAME" value="server2"/>
</propertyfile>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me. I wanted to make this happen for `.properties` file

Comment: Great solution.Thanks

Comment: WARNING:If the key is containing some special characters, It is appended with \ which is an issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<propertyfile file="mypropfile.properties">
    <entry key="Key-1" value="Val-1"/>
</propertyfile>
```

This works seamlessly as long as you have XMLtask defined in your build.xml file.

example#

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="C:/lib">
                <include name="xmltask*.jar"/>
                <include name="xml-apis*.jar"/>
                <include name="xalan*.jar"/>
                <include name="xerces*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="C:/lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```