# Propeties modify using ant

Tags: ant, properties

I want to read a property file using ANT, then modify that property.

```
property.security = true
```

I have to read above the property and need to change to false. How can I do this?

Comment: Please share your ant <target>.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change property values in a file using Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419482/how-can-i-change-property-values-in-a-file-using-ant)

Comment: Do you want to read a property file and just override a value or do you want to read the file, change the value and then save the file?